# Laravel 5.3 pass multiple MessageBag instances to $errors variable

Tags: php, validation, laravel-5

I have two modal fields on a page with forms and need to determine which of the  model fields is has an error.

So my question is:

How can I pass multiple `MessageBag`'s to `$errors` to be able check errors using `$errors->errorType->get('message')`?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, it is called "Named Error Bags":
First need to manually create validator: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation#manually-creating-validators
and then create named bag in response;